# fmap does not work on list of my datatype

Tags: haskell

I have defined my datatype as:

```
data MyMaybe a = Lust a | Lothing deriving (Show,Eq,Ord,Functor, Foldable)
```

When I type `fmap (+3) Lust 4` it gives me the correct answer:  `Lust 7`

But when I type `fmap (+3) [Lust 4, Lust 5]` it does not work and I get the follwoing error:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (MyMaybe a)
```

Please tell me what to do resolve this error.

Comment: Is that a typo in your list? `[Lust 4, List 5]` shouldn't compile.

Comment: Yes it is a typoi

Comment: You can [edit] your question at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmap (+3)` works for a *single* `MyMaybe` in this case. If you want to map a function over a list, you map that function. Let's give `fmap (+3)` a name:

```
myMaybePlus3 :: Num a => MyMaybe a -> MyMaybe a
myMaybePlus3 = fmap (+3)
```

We can now see that it only works for a single `MyMaybe`. We can use `map` (or `fmap`) to use it for a list:

```
map myMaybePlus3 [Lust 4, Lust 5]
```

But due to referential transparency, we can also simply write

```
map (fmap (+3)) [Lust 4, Lust 5]
```

So all you were missing was an additional `(f)map`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the type of `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

When you do

```
fmap (+3) [Lust 4, List 5]
```

You are using `fmap` on a list `[]`, so `f a` in this case is `Num b => [MyMaybe b]`

The implementation of `fmap` on a list is to map all elements of the list. In this case, the elements are `MyMaybe's`. But you can't apply `+3` on your `MyMaybe`s because it isn't a `Num`. If you want you can do:

```
fmap (fmap (+3)) [Lust 4, List 5]
```

This will apply the function `fmap (+3)` on each element of the list.

---

You can use `ghci` to examine types of simple expressions, for example:

```
Prelude> :t fmap (+3)
fmap (+3) :: (Functor f, Num b) => f b -> f b
```

Shows that the argument to `fmap (+3)` must be a functor of some `Num`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are traversing through the list (using `fmap`) and are trying to apply `(+3)` to all elements, but your list elements are of type `Num a => MyMaybe a`.

You need to apply `fmap` twice. Once for traversing the list as you did, and another to traverse each element inside the list which, again, has the type  `Num a => MyMaybe a`.

So the code needs to be:

`fmap (fmap (+3)) [Lust 4, Lust 5]`